# Download and install android app from another android app

Tags: java, android, installation, android-manifest, google-play

Is it possible to download and install android application(from Google Play) from another android application ? If so, could you please provide an example how to implement it? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of the play store application:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "the.package.name");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! One more question - it will start the download process automatically or user should click Download/Install button before ?

Comment: It just opens the application page in the play store app. The user still has to press the install button and to accept the permissions.

Comment: Is there any way to start download process automatically ?

Comment: That would be a security risk, so I don't think it is possible.