# Is it possible to download app from google play from my app - Android

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download and install android app from another android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171025/download-and-install-android-app-from-another-android-app)

I have a client that wants to build an android app that is a list of apps from the google play market.

If the user clicks a button to download the app from google play, is it possible to download the apk directly inside my app, or after the user downloads the app inside the market, be redirected into my app?

The reason this is needed is because the client wants to log to the servers saying the user had downloaded app

Comment: No, it is not possible to do this with the Google Play store. The user will have to return to your app themselves.

An alternative would be downloading the APK from your own server, and prompting them to install it. After that's done they can return back to your app and you could check that the app is installed.

Comment: There is no way google Play can redirect to different app after download. But in google play after app is downloaded there is button to open the same app. One alternate option is to check the list of app installed on the device using this you can find if the app is successfully installed on user device. (this can be done using PackageManager)

Comment: i did find this  http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowDownloadApps